# C++ getline.. i cant avoid reading the ENTER key

Tags: c++, getline

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char user_name[50];
    cout << "what is your name?" << endl;
    cin.getline (user_name, 50, '\n');
    cout << "hello, " << user_name << ", how are you today?" << endl;
}
```

I need the 2nd cout all on one line ,but its reading the enter key even tho i put a delim. how can i fix this?

```
hello, johnny walker
, how are you today?
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax (in an edit). Your code works on my computer and gives the desired output.

Comment: Docs for `getline` say "If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is not stored and the next input operation will begin after it. "

Comment: thanks for the heads up about the meta post.  i went ahead and checked all the answers that helped me on my previous questions. again, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your real code, it should execute exactly how you want.  I just ran it on my Fedora server and it worked perfectly fine, all displaying on one line as you asked.

To save you some pain, and give you a way to store the two parts of a user name separately for better processing, you can try this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string first_name, last_name;
    cin >> first_name >> last_name;
    cout << "Hello " << first_name << " " << last_name << " how are you?" << endl;
}
```

but I'm just giving you that so get you away from getline since you're confused - in reality it should (and does) work fine as well :p

Answer (score 0):

Apart from missing semicolons on line 1 and 3 there is nothing wrong with your code. Does it always break just before the comma?  You might want to have a look at the following link and try some of the hints given there: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/1477/

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine on my Mac OS Lion as it should. Could you provide more information about your environment?

```
hello, johnny walker, how are you today?
```